# JQuery Detect change input where the change was made by JS

Tags: jquery, html, detect

I want to detect a change in the input value where the change was made by JS.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="test_input"><br><br>
<button name="change_input">Change usign JS </button>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('change','input[name="test_input"]',function() {
        alert('Changed');
    });
    $('button[name="change_input"]').on('click',function() {
        $('input[name="test_input"]').val('New value');
    });
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7c54r7x9/

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The change event is only raised when the modification is made by user input. When it's set programmatically you'll need to raise the event yourself. In jQuery, you can do that by using `trigger()`, like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('body').on('change', 'input[name="test_input"]', function() {
    console.log('Changed');
  });

  $('button[name="change_input"]').on('click', function() {
    $('input[name="test_input"]').val('New value').trigger('change');
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="test_input"><br><br>
<button name="change_input">Change usign JS </button>
```

Comment: OMG, good answer!
Do you knwo how detect changed without .trigger ? :) (for future)

Comment: It's not possible. As I mentioned above, changing properties through JS does not raise any events. You could potentially use a MutationObserver if you changed an attribute in the DOM, but in this case using `trigger()` is by far the better solution

Comment: Hmm ok :) Thanks for answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below. Hope this will help you

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="test_input"]').change(function() {
        alert('Changed');
    });
    $('button[name="change_input"]').on('click',function() {
        $('input[name="test_input"]').val('New value');
    $('input[name="test_input"]').trigger("change");
    });
})
```